# How to set placeholder for an img tag in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, html

How do I set a `placeholder` for an image in `img` in `AngularJS`? In my app I am dynamically setting an image using `ng-src`.

Comment: What do you mean by placeholder?

Comment: An image when ng-src is is undefined. The image is a URL.

Comment: set the src of image manually with your placeholder image URL and set the ng-src for the dynamic image you want to be replace on it.

Comment: Did that helped and solved the issue?

Comment: I am using  ng-src={{myModel.avatar}} which will be undefined initially. How do I set it to a URL when it is undefined? kinna like a default value with the DOM

Answer (score 2):

Can use an OR in expression:

```
ng-src="{{myModel.avatar || placeHolderVariable}}"
```